# How to create Carbon object from this string: 2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

How to create DateTime object with PHP from this string: `2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z`? There is nine numbers after 'dot', after seconds.

I tried to use next variants:

```
<?php
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z');
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP', '2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z');
```

And always get an error:

```
The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Comment: Well for a start `Y:m:d` does not match your `2022-06-21`

Comment: Yep, my bad. Anyway, there is still an error: «The timezone could not be found in the database».

Comment: Yup, there are only supposed to be 6 numerics after the `.` and then the `Z`

Comment: Where did you get that date string from?

Comment: `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u???\Z'` should work as long as you have 9 digit milliseconds. PHP can only handle 6 digits

Comment: Or `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u???P`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it's from Ozon Seller API: https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/en/#section/Product-price-index-change

Comment: Solutions go in Answers, not Questions. You are quite at libery to post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format should be as follows to cope with the 9 numerics after the `.` PHP only can cope with 6 numerics so the `?` are just place holders for anything

```
<?php
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u???P', '2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z');
```

Answer (score 1):

`'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u???P'` format as per RiggsFolly's solution is the way if you expect only this format.

If you want to allow more or less digits, note that `parse` can also do it without having to specify any format:

```php
echo Carbon::parse('2022-06-21T05:52:46.648533678Z');
```